# What does it imply when two lines cross each other in a level curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

[image]

I'm having trouble to articulate how the actual graph looks like when z = 0, meaning in the middle of the level curve where intersection occurs.

What shape would the graph look like and what curvature is it supposed to have?

Comment: I don't follow your question.  If we were to take slices of the image parallel to the $x$-$y$ plane at certain values of $z$, we would get the slice corresponding to $z=1$ creates a graph looking like a hyperbola.  If we look at the slice where $z=0$ then this is just two intersecting lines rather than two "curvy" curves.

Comment: Think of it as being at the top of a mountain pass.  Behind you and in front of you, the ground slopes downward.  to your left and right, the ground rises up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [hyperbolic paraboloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid#Hyperbolic_paraboloid) has has a pair of horizontal lines crossing at the central saddle point. That's a level *set*, but not a level *curve*.

A level set is the intersection of a surface with a plane.  If the surface is smooth that will be a one dimensional object in the plane. Sometimes it will be a single curve in the usual sense - then you would call it a level curve. But it might be an intersection of lines or curves, or come in several pieces. Then calling it a level curve is a mild abuse of language, but will not confuse anyone.

[image]
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hyperbolic-paraboloid.svg

Comment: Thanks! Level set is basically a set that contains the level curve, is that correct?

Comment: @JohnnyYang See my edit.

Comment: What would be the difference between smooth surface and a single curve? I thought even if it's a smooth surface, it will still at most occupy the span of 2 variables thus making it a 2-dimensional object instead.

Comment: The surface is a two dimensional object in three space. A level set is a one dimensional object in a plane - just as in the picture in the question. The level set for $z=1$ is a hyperbola. The level set of $z=0$ is two intersecting lines (which is a degenerate hyperbola).

Comment: Ahh I get it now, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [saddle point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point), like a Pringle. If you move in certain direction away from the origin (positive or negative $x$-directions) the function will increase, while if you move away from the origin in other directions (positive or negative $y$-directions) the function will decrease.